# Textbox using Calendar Extender losing value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a textbox using a CalendarExtender and some other controls for validation, here's the code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPrazoData" MaxLength="10" Width="80" />
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="cePrazoData" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtPrazoData" />

<ajax:MaskedEditValidator runat="server" ID="mevPrazoDataModal" ControlToValidate="txtPrazoData" InvalidValueMessage="<%$ Resources:Base, DataInvalida %>" InvalidValueBlurredMessage="*" Text="*" 
ControlExtender="meePrazoData" ErrorMessage="*" EmptyValueMessage="<%$ Resources:Base, CampoRequerido %>"
IsValidEmpty="false" EmptyValueBlurredText="*" ValidationGroup="GrpAcaoModal">*</ajax:MaskedEditValidator>

<ajax:MaskedEditExtender runat="server" ID="meePrazoData" TargetControlID="txtPrazoData" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date"/>
<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vcePrazoData" TargetControlID="mevPrazoDataModal" runat="server"/>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvPrazoData" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPrazoData" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources: Base, DataInvalida %>" Display="None" ValidationGroup="GrpAcaoModal" />
<ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vcePrazoDataCompare" runat="server" TargetControlID="cvPrazoData" />
```

When I select the textbox and pick a date from the calendar and then select another control of the form, the textbox simply loses it's value:
[image]

If I type the value instead of selecting it from the calendar, it doesn't disappear. There is no postback happening and the textbox has no TextChanged event or any other associated.
If I try to do this using IE's compatibility mode, it works. If it helps, I'm using IE9 version 9.0.8112.16421.

Comment: What version of the Ajax Control toolkit library and ASP.NET do use? Did you try to reproduce this issue by pasting markup from your post to blank page?

Comment: I'm not sure 'cause I did not implement this, but if I lookup the properties of the AjaxControlToolkit dll reference in the project, the version is 3.0.30512.1 and runtime version v2.0.50727. I don't know what you mean by "reproduce this issue by pasting markup from your post to blank page".

Comment: I tried to reproduce it on my local environment and I wasn't able to reproduce this issue. I used markup from you post.

Comment: What happens if you remove all the controls except the textbox,calendar extender and the masked editor extender?Do you still get the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I bet that your validator disables this value. Check if calendar and your validator have the same date format.

Comment: I took off the validator and the other controls leaving just the Textbox and the CalendarExtender and still happens.